# How to get the correct parameters for the googleapi-nodejs-client

Tags: google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using [Google's officially supported Node.js client library for accessing Google APIs.](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)

But I am struggling to find the correct parameters for the api calls. The closest I have as a reference is [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) but I still have no idea what the parameters are I have to use in the nodejs api (and what they mean).

So the only thing I have is searching for code samples in the internet and trial and error. Isn't there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, when I use the Google APIs in a script, I always use the following flow.

#### Sample situation:

I would like to explain this using a sample situation. As the sample situation, I retrieve the file list from the specific folder in Google Drive using [the method of Files: list in Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list).

#### Flow:

1. Access to [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer).
2. Search Drive API v3. And go to the reference page of Drive API v3. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/)
3. Access to "Files: list". [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
4. Here, you can see the parameters for using "Files: list". [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list#parameters)
5. In order to search the files, here, `q` is used. In this case, you can see the link to "[Search for files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)".

   - From "Search for files", it is found that the required search query is `'1234567' in parents`.
6. Here, use "Try this API".

   - Please click a square button. You can see it at the following image.

     [image]
   - By this, you can see the opened window as shown in the following image.

     [image]
   - Put `'###' in parents` to `q` of "Request parameters". `###` is the folder ID. By this, the curl sample is also changed. Also, you can test the API using "Try this API".

     ```
     curl \
       'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%27###%27%20in%20parents&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
       --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
       --header 'Accept: application/json' \
       --compressed
     ```
   - If you want to confirm the Javascript sample, you can also see it as follows.

     ```
     function execute() {
       return gapi.client.drive.files.list({
           "q": "'###' in parents"
         })
         .then(function(response) {
             // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
             console.log("Response", response);
           },
           function(err) {
             console.error("Execute error", err);
           });
     }
     ```

In my case, from the curl sample, I implement the request to the script.

Also, when I use the request to Google API using googleapis with each language, I check the script at the GitHub of each googleapis. For example, when I create a script using Node.js, I check googleapis for Node.js as you mentioned in your question.

#### Reference:

- [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer)

Comment: @zlZimon Thank you for replying. If this was useful for your situation, I'm glad.